# just started mvc 4 where can i adjust bundles

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, bundle

I just started mvc4 and on the **_layout** I see 2 new elements

```
  <link href="@System.Web.Optimization.BundleTable.Bundles.ResolveBundleUrl("~/Content/css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="@System.Web.Optimization.BundleTable.Bundles.ResolveBundleUrl("~/Scripts/js")"></script>
```

As i have read these bundles are used to load everything together thus saving time, I use jquery alot so i modified my **_layout** so that the header now looks like this

```
<link href="@System.Web.Optimization.BundleTable.Bundles.ResolveBundleUrl("~/Content/css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="@System.Web.Optimization.BundleTable.Bundles.ResolveBundleUrl("~/Scripts/js")"></script>

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js")" type="text/javascript">
```

to allow Jquery, this defeats the purpose of the bundle so my question is how can I include that final jquery file inside the JS bundle ? I can't seem to find where those bundles would be, I looked inside Global.asax and was not there.

Comment: app_start  bundleconfig.cs

Comment: Read this http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/bundling-and-minification

Answer (score 4):

In ASP.NET MVC4, if you are following in default project template, there are two places which are concerned with bundling facility:

In Global.asax.cs you register your bundles in Application_Start method:

```
   protected void Application_Start()
   { 
    ......
    BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);        
   }
```

Now in App_Start folder you have BundleConfig.cs file. In this file there are some by default css and js bundles created by template. 
In RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles) method you can add your files in existing bundles or create your own bundle exactly what you need:

```
     public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
     {
       bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/yourNewBundleName").Include(
                            "~/Scripts/yourFile1",
                                 "~/Scripts/ yourFile2"));
     }
```

Here instead of "~/bundles/yourNewBundleName" you can give name of bundle as per you ease and include all files needed then and refer it in _Layout.cshtml or any other views. By referring it all the files which you have included will be available there.